# Location should consist of two numerical values

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, folium

Using Jupyter Notebook

making map

**place_lat** is

```
[37.4601908,
 37.4785259,
 37.5618288,
 37.5672412,
 37.4601908,
 37.526152,
 37.504487,
 37.5277524,
 37.526152,
 37.681997,
 37.642134]
```

**place_lng** is

```
[126.4406957,
 126.6685039,
 126.8019274,
 127.0056589,
 126.4406957,
 127.028504,
 127.048957,
 127.01948,
 127.028504,
 126.77004,
 126.8312317]
```

and I got error at here

```
map = folium.Map(location=[37.4601908, 126.4406957], zoom_start=11)

for n in place_name:
    folium.Marker([place_lat,
                  place_lng]).add_to(map)

map
```

error says

```
ValueError: Location should consist of two numerical values, but [37.4601908, 37.4785259, 37.5618288, 37.5672412, 37.4601908, 37.526152, 37.504487, 37.5277524, 37.526152, 37.681997, 37.642134] of type <class 'list'> is not convertible to float.
```

should I have to change list to float?

how can I fix it?

Comment: in `folium.Marker([place_lat, place_lng])` you are passing complete list rather it should be a float value e.g. `folium.Marker([45.3311, -121.7113])`

Comment: thanks! Than I have to change all like this?  `folium.Marker([37.4601908, 126.4406957]), folium.Marker([37.4785259, 126.4406957]), folium.Marker([37.5618288, 126.4406957]), folium.Marker([37.4601908, 126.4406957]) ... `

Comment: No, you can iterate over your list, posting in answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to iterate over your lat,long list:

```
for index,lat in enumerate(place_lat):
folium.Marker([lat,
               place_lng[index]]).add_to(map)
```

I am assuming you have same length of `place_lat` and `place_lang`.

`enumerate` over a list will return you index and value in the list.